# Почему, используя requests и VK API, получаю неполную информацию о странице

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, requests

Пробую работать с модулем requests и VK API, чтобы быстро получать информацию о нужной странице (к примеру)

```
import requests as rq
token = "Его нельзя показывать"
version = 5.131
source = "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get"

person ="shvabar" #случайный человек
info = rq.get(source,
            params = {
                'access_token':token,
                'v':version,
                'user_ids': person,
                'fields': {'relation','bdate', 'sex', 'can_write_private_message', 'friends'}
            })

print(info)
jsoninfo = info.json()

print(jsoninfo)
relat = jsoninfo.get('response')[0].get("relation")
print(jsoninfo.get('response')[0].get("relation"))
print(jsoninfo.get('response')[0].get("bdate"))
print(jsoninfo.get('response')[0].get("sex"))
print(jsoninfo.get('response')[0].get("can_write_private_message")) 
print(jsoninfo.get('response')[0].get("friends"))
```

Выводится в консоль следующее

```
<Response [200]>
{'response': [{'id': 20210511, 'relation': 1, 'first_name': 'Mikhail', 'last_name': 'Averyanov', 'can_access_closed': True, 'is_closed': False}]}
1
None
None
None
None
```

Несколько раз запуская, выводится нужна информация заместо None. Т.е. значение бывает иногда у relation, иногда у can_write_private_message, иногда у bdate

В чем проблема? Как пофиксить, чтобы за один запрос всё нормально выводилось

upd:
ссылка вводится вот такая

```
#https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?
#access_token= нельзя
#&v=5.131
#&user_ids=shvabar
#&fields=relation
#&fields=friends
#&fields=bdate
#&fields=sex
#&fields=can_write_private_message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно было использовать вместо

```
'fields': {'relation','bdate', 'sex', 'can_write_private_message', 'friends'}
```

вот это

```
'fields': 'relation, bdate, sex, can_write_private_message, friends'
```

потому что нам нужен запрос

```
fields=relation,friends,bdate,sex,can_write_private_message
```

а не

```
fields=relation&fields=friends&fields=bdate&fields=sex&fields=can_write_private_message
```